# Is it good to delete when reading ( adding each statement to delete ) and doing a batch delete at the end or do a single delete?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Archive and delete process. Which one is recommended?

This process runs end of the day when the window is closed to any extraneous transactions other than this one to disallow interference with the below tx.

I. Batch delete

```
object = read()

while ( hasNext() ) 
{
  object = next();
  call the archive_process to archive the object.
  add to delete.
}

batch_delete.
```

II. Single delete statement.

```
object = read()

while ( hasNext() ) 
{
  object = next();
  call the archive_process to archive the object.
}

use the same sql as above, but instead delete in a single statement.
```

Which one is recommended?

Comment: It will depend. I would prefer to use a single delete where it specifies all the data to delete.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, that's what I thought of doing ( using a single delete statement ), but, just wanted to check. Thanks!

Comment: If another transaction adds a new item that satisfies the read query while you're doing the archival, the second solution will delete it without archiving it.

Comment: Remember that it will depend on different circumstances, note the comment by JBNizet.

Comment: @JBNizet This process runs end of the day when the window is closed to any extraneous transactions other than this one. I should have said that in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Also look at JDBC's batched statements. That is probably the most efficient way if you need separate DELETE statements (instead of one statement with a really big `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your specific needs:

- If your code require that every record is deleted so it can perform other tasks, deleting one row at a time on each loop may be needed.
- If your code can do its tasks independently of wether a record is deleted or not, deleting everything at the end (on a single batch) would be better.

You need to remember that every `delete` triggers an action on your data, and may have an impact on disk read-write speed of your program. A single batch delete may have a positive impact on the speed of your code compared with many one-row delete operations.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to other answers - check also you have enough UNDO to support DELETE command. Also, with bigger volume DELETE can become tooo slow - check if alternatives exist. Be aware also of the impact of many indexes.